# MySQL Error #1064 on this INSERT from PHPBB

Tags: mysql, phpbb

I'm completely out of my depth here but could use some help as some SQL code has broken on a PHPBB site I've run for the last ten years.

I can sometimes post on the board but other times I see this message:

> SQL Error : 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near...

The code that's failing is:

> INSERT INTO phpbb_posts_text (post_id, post_subject, bbcode_uid,
>   post_text) VALUES (28612, 'Testing', '0e2d19fcc7', 'I've been having
>   some problems with the site recently. Is it working for other people?
>   Are you seeing strange SQL Debug messages?')

And the code from the php reads:

```
$sql = ($mode != 'editpost') ? 
    "INSERT INTO " . POSTS_TEXT_TABLE . "
    (post_id, post_subject, bbcode_uid, post_text) 
    VALUES ($post_id, '$post_subject', '$bbcode_uid', '$post_message')" 
    : "UPDATE " . POSTS_TEXT_TABLE . " SET post_text = '$post_message',  bbcode_uid =
    '$bbcode_uid', post_subject = '$post_subject' WHERE post_id = $post_id";
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: **WARNING**: This has some severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) because `$_GET` data is used inside the query. Whenever possible use **prepared statements**. These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.

Answer (score 1):

`$post_message` contains a quote character, which is terminating the string. You need to escape the value to prevent SQL-injection errors like this.

But it would be best if you switched to prepared statements instead of substituting variables directly into the SQL query. You need to use PDO or mysqli for this.

Comment: Ah. Thank you. I've been running this code for the last ten years without issues. Is there a change to PHP recently that would have caused this?

Where is the quote character? Is it the apostrophe in I've?

It's not my code so I'm going to be careful when trying to patch it. Any advice?

Comment: Nothing has changed, you just never got a message with an apostrophe before, so you've been lucky. Apostrophe and quote are the same character.